# Find the list of all the AWS ALB target groups in which instance is registered

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

For `ELB`, if we want to remove the instance from all the elbs, we just need to pass the instance id to the `elb_instance` module and again if we want to add the instance back in the same playbook, it give us a magic variable `ec2_elbs`, we can iterate over this variable and add back or register the instance to all the elbs which he was registered previously.

I didn't find any module, which I can use to find the list of the target groups in which the instance is register. can somebody point if know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to dynamically removed the instance(s) from all the target groups that it has been registered:

```
- name: Collect facts about EC2 Instance
  action: ec2_metadata_facts

- name: Get the list of all target groups to which Instance(s) registered
  local_action:
    module: elb_target_facts
    instance_id: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
    region: "{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
  register: alb_target_facts
  become: no

- name: Deregister the Instance from all target groups
  local_action:
    module: elb_target
    target_group_arn: "{{ item.target_group_arn }}"
    target_id: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
    region: "{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
    target_status_timeout: 300
    target_status: unused
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ alb_target_facts.instance_target_groups }}"
  become: no
```

Because I have registered the target group(s) information in a variable, I can use it again to add it back:

```
- name: Register the Instance back to the target group(s)
  local_action:
    module: elb_target
    target_group_arn: "{{ item.target_group_arn }}"
    target_id: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
    region: "{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
    target_status: healthy
    target_status_timeout: 300
    state: present
  loop: "{{ alb_target_facts.instance_target_groups }}"
  become: no
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [elb_target_group](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/elb_target_group_module.html) module which is in preview mode or you can make use of a python script and boto to find the list of instances in a particular targetgroup

Comment: thanks.. I am using `elb_target` target group to remove the instance from single target group but I want a dynamic approach in which instance is register to multiple target groups. any suggestion on this? happy to use python if you point me to some link